# Is T(n) >= T(n-1) always true?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

I saw a proof for finding complexity of a sorting algorithm which says something like this :

```
Total time complexity for the algorithm = T(n-1) + T(n-2)

Thus, Total time complexity for the algorithm <= 2 * T( n-2 )
```

and further went on to prove some relation.

Ques: Can I always safely assume that `T(n) >= T(n-1)` ? When I am already trying to prove the complexity of some algorithm, how can I make this claim before hand ?

Comment: Yes, if `Task(n-2)` is SUBTASK of `Task(n-1)`.  It is true for sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot do such a claim.

Consider a function:

```
f(0) = 1000000! (factorial of 1000000)
f(n) = 1, for n>0
```

Here, time complexity of the function with bigger argument is smaller then the lower one.

Everything depends on the details, in particular - in provided example you already have a statement

```
Total time complexity for the algorithm = T(n-1) + T(n-2)
```

which is equivalent to

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)
```

which is a strong claim about the complexity, but it does not seem right to assume

```
Thus, Total time complexity for the algorithm <= 2 * T( n-2 )
```

as we can deducde from

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2)
```

that

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) = (T(n-2) + T(n-3)) + T(n-2) >= 2 * T( n-2 )
```

maybe the claim was this?

```
Thus, Total time complexity for the algorithm >= 2 * T( n-2 )
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot always make this assumption, it depends on the function T.

For example:

```
T(0) = T(1) = 1 //no important
T(2n) = T(2n-2) //all even numbers are calculated recursivel
T(2n+1) = 1 //all odd numbers
```

In the above, for every odd `n`: T(n) < T(n-1)

A practical example where this might actually be a complexity function is if `n` has to be even, and if it is not - an error is returned.

Answer (score 0):

No, depends on the algorithm.

I could define an algorithm like this : For every input of size `n < 1000` try to do something. if `n > 1000` return some conclusive decision.

So for every `n < 1000` there could be a long and tiring calculation, but for `n > 1000` it's `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

`T(n) >= 2*T(n-2)` is implied, for `n>3`, by the recurrence relation `T(n) = T(n-1)+T(n-2)`.

`T(n-1)` is `T(n-2)+T(n-3)`.

If `T` represents the cost of an algorithm, it cannot be negative.

`T(n-3) >= 0` implies `T(n-1) >= T(n-2)`, and `T(n) >= 2*T(n-2)`.

This is just a consequence of the specific recurrence relation, not something you can assume in general, though it is true for many recurrence relations that arise in algorithm analysis.